# How could I add a status bar that shows if it safe to remove my external hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive

Whenever I want to remove my hard drive I never know when I can safely remove it. How do I add a status bar that indicates when?

Comment: Not really an answer to your question, but you can simple umount your external hard drive. It's the equivalent command line option (umount /dev/<drive address> OR umount /media/<drive folder>).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an indicator for safely removing USB devices and the good news is that it seems to be maintained:

[image]

- Source: [USB Safe Removal](https://askubuntu.com/a/37989/248158) which points to [indicator-usb](https://github.com/cas--/indicator-usb/releases/tag/v0.2.2).

Notice that this application is currently not available in the Ubuntu Software Center and so you'll be downloading a `.deb` file. While downloading, choose "Save as" in your browser and not "Open with". After downloading, right-click and the file (in your file manager) and choose Open with USC (Ubuntu Software Center). This will cause the .deb file to be automatically unpacked and installed for you.

Please be informed that I have no first-hand experience with this indicator. I unmount devices from my file manager by right-clicking on the device and choosing unmount/eject. I also make sure to do this some time after I've finished writing to the device,

Hope this helps!